# Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'TYPE' so +entity is unable to disambiguate using CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to usave stuff in CoreData. This is the first time I'm trying to implement it in an application. But I have some problems when I try to save something apparently.

When I try to save the data I get these errors in console :

> 2023-01-26 14:40:17.640995+0100 YoddChatGpt[69668:1444975] [error] warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Message' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
> CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Message' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
> 2023-01-26 14:40:17.641127+0100 YoddChatGpt[69668:1444975] [error] warning:      'Message' (0x600003c84210) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x6000028b8cd0) claims 'Message'.
> CoreData: warning:       'Message' (0x600003c84210) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x6000028b8cd0) claims 'Message'.
> 2023-01-26 14:40:17.641201+0100 YoddChatGpt[69668:1444975] [error] warning:      'Message' (0x600003c80fd0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x6000028adf40) claims 'Message'.
> CoreData: warning:       'Message' (0x600003c80fd0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x6000028adf40) claims 'Message'.
> 2023-01-26 14:40:17.641258+0100 YoddChatGpt[69668:1444975] [error] error: +[Message entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
> CoreData: error: +[Message entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
> Data saved
> `

This is the DataController I created:

```
class DataController : ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MessageModel")
    
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { desc, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR >>> Failed to load the data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the funciton for saving

```
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
        } catch {
            print("ERROR >>> Data couldn't be saved")
        }
    }
    
    
    func addMessage (body : String, sender: String, context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let message = Message(context: context)
        message.date = Date()
        message.body = body
        message.id = UUID()
        message.sender = sender == "bot" ? "bot" : "user"
        
        save(context: context)
    }
```

This is how I enject CoreData into the view

```
    @Environment (\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]) var messages : FetchedResults<Message>
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
```

and this is how I inject it into the app file

```
struct YoddChatGptApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
//    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ChatView2()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Ok so the solution was create a shared istance, without creating everytime a new one.

```
class DataController : ObservableObject {
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MessageModel")

static let shared = DataController()

init() {
    container.loadPersistentStores { desc, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR >>> Failed to load the data \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

...
}

And injecting it the right way

```
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController.shared
```

//    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ChatView2()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Double check if you are initialising `DataController` anywhere else in your code, you should use only one instance so you don't use different NSPersistentContainer. Unrelated but I don't think DataController needs to conform to ObservableObject

Comment: I fixed id by adding a shared instance, I'm going to update the solution.